# Access 2013 form not updating when navigation button pressed

Tags: forms, ms-access, macros, navigation

First time on site. Forgive me, I'm probably doing this wrong, but I have searched for 2 days and not found my answer.
After entering data in the Lead Maintenance form, clicking the Registrar tab runs the following macro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<UserInterfaceMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
<UserInterfaceMacro For="navbtnRegistrar" Event="OnClick">
<Statements>
<Action Name="SetWarnings"/>
<Action Collapsed="true" Name="OpenQuery">
<Argument Name="QueryName">qryEnroll</Argument>
</Action>
<Action Name="OpenQuery">
<Argument Name="QueryName">qryLeadMainUpdateEnrollToTrue</Argument>
</Action>
<Action Name="SetWarnings">
<Argument Name="WarningsOn">Yes</Argument>
</Action>
<Action Name="OpenForm">
<Argument Name="FormName">frmStudentsData</Argument>
</Action>
<Action Name="CloseWindow">
<Argument Name="ObjectType">Form</Argument>
<Argument Name="ObjectName">frmStudentsData</Argument>
<Argument Name="Save">No</Argument>
</Action>
</Statements>
</UserInterfaceMacro>
</UserInterfaceMacros>
```

The new data is being appended to the table properly, however the New Student data form is not displaying the appended data. Any suggestions?

[image: Lead Maintenance Form]

[image: Student Data Form]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Student Data Entry form is in "Data Entry" mode, so it will automatically only show a blank record for your users to fill out.  You would need to turn off Data Entry mode, a property on the form itself and turn on the navigation bar that you already have on the Lead Maintenance form so that users can navigate between records.